# Mobile Page Slider content with dynamic height

Tags: jssor

I am trying to implement the app that have 4 pages in 4 table. It supposed to be support swipe gesture, and each page contains dynamic data and make the pages have different height.

I tried to use responsive-slider-div-span.source example and integrate the 4 table into the slides.

I would like to set the width and height for the slides dynamically while the document ready, However, The slide will not show if the width and height is not pre set in the the slide div.

May I know any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, the size of jssor slider is defined in html code, and you can alter the size grammatically.

Given a slider at size 600x300, you can use javascript to change size before initialization of jssor slider.

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {};

        //retrieve height of the slider, assuming the height should be 200px;
        $("#slider1_container").height("200px");
        $("#slider1_slides").height("200px");

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

        //According to your comment, please add following code
        //Handle $EVT_PARK event BEGIN
        function OnSliderPark(slideIndex, fromIndex) {
            if (slideIndex == 0 || slideIndex == jssor_slider1.$SlidesCount() - 1) {
                //do something scroll page to top
            }
        }

        jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, OnSliderPark);
        //Handle $EVT_PARK event END
    });
</script>

<div id="slider1_container" style="... width: 600px; height: 300px; ...">
    <div u="slides" id="slider1_slides" style="... width: 600px; height: 300px; ...">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear jssor, may i know how can I handle the dynamic data as the height varies?

Comment: Use $("#id").height() to retrieve height of an element.

Comment: Currently, the performance of the slider is quite slow in mobile compared with the emulator in Chrome browser. Can you advise is there and way that can help to light the js library?

Comment: One more question is currently the slides height is set once, how about the pages with different height? can i set another slides class for different pages?

Comment: To speed up animation on mobile device, please try to disable hardware acceleration by setting $HWA to false.

Comment: To set different class for different page, you need detect page height manually, and set set class name for 'outer container' and 'slides' container before the slider initializes.

Comment: That mean for page with different height, put it into different container class?

Comment: Typically, the slider size depends on size of 'outer container' and 'slides' container. If you change size of 'outer container' and 'slides' container, the size of slider should be different. That's to say, in different page, you need to specify different size for 'outer container' and slides container. You can specify size by inline style or by different class name.

Comment: Hi Jssor, one more thing that i would like you to help. Can I add one more action that to move to the top of the page while the page is swipe to left or right? If yes, where should I add on it. Or the library is needed to update for this function?

Comment: Hi Jssor, May I know any place I can add to do some action before the swipe function start? If yes, where should I place it?

Comment: Please use jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_SWIPE_START, function (position) { });

Comment: And jssor_slider1.$IsDragging(); lets you know if  the swipe is by drag or not.

Comment: If position is an integer, it means it swipes from one slide to another. If position is a float value, it means the swipe starts from a interrupt (e.g. end of drag).

Comment: And another api  jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE, function (position, fromPosition) { }); always reports the position where the sliding goes.